# Acer laptop screen won't start unless I click fn+f4 help needed

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Acer laptop screen won't start unless i click fn+f4](https://superuser.com/questions/413222/acer-laptop-screen-wont-start-unless-i-click-fnf4)

I have an Acer laptop. When I turn it on, the screen turns on and then turns off before the Windows 7 login screen appears. The screen won't turn on unless I press Fn+F4 and F4 again. What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with updating your BIOS and resetting your BIOS settings to factory defaults afterwards. If you do not have another monitor connected it should not be doing this. If you are continuing to have this issue I'd recommend contacting Acer as it is unlikely (but not impossible) for a BIOS setting to be overriding this.